# install spark packages in toree

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I usually start my spark-shell with:

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0,graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1
```

I'm trying to use Apache Toree now, any idea of how should I load these libraries on the notebook?

I tried the following:

```
jupyter toree install --user --spark_home=/home/eron/spark-1.6.1/ --spark_opts="--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0,graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:2.0.1"
```

but that did not seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify packages in the `SPARK_OPTS` environment variable:

```
export SPARK_OPTS='--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0'
```

Modifying `spark-defaults.conf` also works:

```
echo spark.jars.packages=com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 | sudo tee -a $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Answer (score 10):

When you have Apache Toree correctly installed as a kernel for Jupyter, you can define Maven dependencies from within a notebook cell like this:

```
%AddDeps org.apache.spark spark-mllib_2.10 1.6.2
%AddDeps com.github.haifengl smile-core 1.1.0 --transitive
%AddDeps io.reactivex rxscala_2.10 0.26.1 --transitive
%AddDeps com.chuusai shapeless_2.10 2.3.0 --repository https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/
%AddDeps org.tmoerman plongeur-spark_2.10 0.3.9 --repository file:/Users/tmo/.m2/repository
```

(excerpt from [this notebook](https://github.com/tmoerman/plongeur/blob/master/scala/plongeur-spark/plongeur-nb/Plongeur%20dependencies.ipynb))

`%AddDeps` is a so-called *magic*, as documented in the Spark-kernel (now renamed Toree) [wiki](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel/wiki/List-of-Current-Magics-for-the-Spark-Kernel).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use %AddDeps within your notebook. For example, something like this:

```
%AddDeps "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.1.0-spark1.6" --repository http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven
```